# How to load a XPCOM component when Firefox's content process is created (e10s)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, e10s

I'm trying to override Firefox's default implementation of `nsIURIFixup` via a Firefox addon. Because this service [is created once and then cached globally after the construction of `nsDocShell`](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/1c070487cfcb/docshell/base/nsDocShell.cpp#l892), I have to register my component *before any docshell is initialized*. Therefore I use `chrome.manifest` to register my (JS) XPCOM component, including the `profile-after-change` category to get the component to load as soon as possible.

This works well in single-process Firefox (37), but not when Electrolysis (e10s) is enabled (e.g. in Firefox Nightly). This issue is caused by the fact that an add-on's `chrome.manifest` is only imported in Firefox's browser process, and not its content processes when e10s is activate ([bug 596880](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596880), marked as WontFix).

Components can dynamically be registered in the content process by [importing a JSM in a frame script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/The_message_manager#Loading_scripts_per_child_process) which calls the [`registerFactory` method of `nsIComponentRegistrar`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIComponentRegistrar#registerFactory()). This probably works for most applications, but not for mine because my component *must* be initialized before the docshell is constructed, and it appears that frame scripts are loaded too late (i.e. when the docshell has already been constructed).

I've also explored other ways to implement my functionality, such as tracking down and monkey-patching the (indirect) consumers of the interface. I dislike this fragile "solution", because it relies on undocumented implementation details and may therefore break at any point in the future.
It also occurred to me that I could append my component to Firefox's global `chrome.manifest`, but this seems like a terrible hack as well (what if this file is read-only, e.g. because it is installed by an admin? And what are the odds that AMO accepts an add-on that modifies one of Firefox's core files as a part of its installation...?).

So, how can I properly register a component that loads as soon as a content process is created, such that it can effectively override an implementation of an interface within that process?

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks! I hope to receive a useful answer, but if not, then at least the implicit questions and answers that are buried between the lines in my post might be of use to others.

Comment: you could try the [loadProcessScript](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsIMessageManager.idl#434) (fairly new and undocumented) instead of loadFrameScript. maybe that'll work

Comment: @the8472 Thanks for the suggestion. That's certainly more elegant than using a JSM + loadFrameScript, but it still runs too late (after the construction of the docshell).

Comment: I see. Maybe you should ask the devs on #e10s on mozilla's IRC, they might know an answer.

Comment: I think RobW is not a regular on IRC. Ill ask for you man.

Comment: @Noitidart In fact I am (using nick robwu_nl). I discovered https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1131065 and found that no-one was working on it, so I checked out Firefox's source code, started compiling and debugging, and now I'm ready to try and write a patch.